# Does C# have a way to &&=?

Tags: c#, boolean, readability

I have several booleans I need to check and turn into a single boolean for readability:

```
bool myBoolean = 5 == 5 && "string" == "String" && true && false && CheckSomethingElse();
```

Is there a way I can break this up into multiple lines to make it more readable?  I can do this:

```
bool myBoolean = 5 == 5;
myBoolean = myBoolean && "string" == "String";
myBoolean = myBoolean && true;
myBoolean = myBoolean && false;
myBoolean = myBoolean && CheckSomethingElse();
```

But I am looking for something more along the lines of this:

```
bool myBoolean = 5 == 5;
myBoolean &= "string" == "String";
myBoolean &= true;
myBoolean &= false;
myBoolean &= CheckSomethingElse();
```

However, the third code block does not do the same thing as the first/second (as far as I know).  Does C# have a way to improve the readability from the first code block?  Or is there some sort of a normal way to code such a boolean?

Comment: create an appropriately named  method

Comment: BTW.. breaking up your condition into multiple lines like that makes readability much worse.  One statement is allowed to span multiple lines, so just put a new line before each of the && in your first one line sample.

Comment: Go to MSDN and look for the c# operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I may agree with some of JK and etc. opinions about rewriting, but to actually answer your question according to SO guidelines, The correct answer is No because that operator is not defined in C# and you can not overload a new operator like that for the Boolean type.

I think the best you can get is defining an extension method for the Boolean type

```
  public static class BoolExtension{

    public static bool And(this Boolean first, bool second){
      first =  first && second;
      return first;
    }
     public static bool MultiAnd(this Boolean first, params bool[] others)
    {
        foreach (var b in others) first = first && b;
        return first;
    }
}
```

and then use it like this

```
bool myBoolean = 5 == 5;
myBoolean.And( "string" == "String");
myBoolean.MultiAnd("A"=="A","B"=="C","D"=="D");
```

As you can see, this may  not help much with readability.

Some people end up implementing a Decorator pattern for the Boolean class in such cases by defining a struct/class that has a Boolean inside it and does operator overloading that you like.

Comment: please do not define such an extension method!!! -> "As you can see, this may not help much with readability." !!

Comment: @MitchWheat Personally I never do

Comment: Why do you need different methods for a single `bool` and multi `bool` if you are using `params`? If you remove `And` and rename `MultiAnd` to `And`, it will work the same way :)

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev yep. I noticed that too, but this is just to give examples

Answer (score 7):

For readability, simply extract it out into a named method where the name of the method instantly tells you the intent:

```
public bool FluxCapacitorIsReady()
{
    return 5 == 5 
           && "string" == "String" 
           && true 
           && false 
           && CheckSomethingElse();
}
```

Now you can just call that method in your code and it is immediately clear to any reader what is going on:

```
if (FluxCapacitorIsReady())
    StartFluxCapacitor();
```

This is a concept from Clean Code: see http://cleancoders.com for more.

Comment: This doesn't answer the whole question. It gives a great alternative, but it's not a complete answer.

Comment: it answers the question " I need to check and turn into a single boolean for readability:"

Comment: @MitchWheat - I was more thinking about the title "Does C# have a way to &&=?".

Comment: @Enigmativity: Sometimes the best answer is "don't do that".  :)  There's no decent way to break up the statement and keep the semantics of `&&`.

Comment: @JK. - I going to disagree with "is immediately clear to any reader". As soon as you put the logic within the `FluxCapacitorIsReady` method you are hiding what is going on. I prefer to see `if (SpeedGreaterThanEqualTo(88) && UraniumLoadedInFluxCapacitor())`. I get that this much the same thing, but it's much easier to reason with when glancing at methods broken down in this way - both at the method implementation and usage sites.

Comment: @Enigmativity hiding details is the whole point. You think hard, but once about what you mean with this group of conditions and than use it everywhere (or even in single place). Completely opinion based - pick whatever way you like and do it - also this is an easy tests that allows to learn about teams/team members to quickly see which side they are on (nothing particularly wrong about either approach).

Comment: @Enigmativity: Hiding what's going on is generally a _good_ thing. You don't care whether you're moving at 88 MPH and have uranium. (Plutonium, actually, IIRC.) You care whether the flux capacitor is ready to fire up. The code should say that. The details are easy to find if you need them, but quite often, you don't.

Comment: @Enigmativity I would put those two methods inside of `FluxCapacitorIsReady` and make sure that I have unit tests that prove that it only starts when it is ready.  If in the future you get a bug report "flux capacitor started when it was not ready", you know exactly where to look.  Until then, you don't need to think about how the test is implemented.

Comment: @JK. - I just feel that move complex `if` logic from code to a method isn't making it better - it's just moving it. If there's an error it is now somewhere else and if there is an error it is harder to spot. Splitting the complex logic into simple conditions and then aggregating them is cleaner coding, IMHO.

Comment: This could've been a great answer if it was in CodeReview